# Activity getting stopped with CursorIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, android, cursor

Hi guys I am facing an error while compiling my code and I couldn't understand what does it mean..I need some assistance..

giving my codes below..

```
            public String  updateEntry(String empcode,String confirm_password)
             {
       String update="Update Signup set PASSWORD = '" + confirm_password + "' " + " 
       WHERE EMPLOYEE_CODE = " + " '" + empcode + "' ";


       Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(update, null);

        String uppassword=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));

        return uppassword;

           }
```

the code returns the correct output ...but error exists..and activity getting stopped..

giving my logcat below..

```
10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at 
android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at com.neochat.LoginDataBaseAdapter.updateEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:145)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at com.neochat.Forgotpassword.attemptforgot(Forgotpassword.java:157)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at com.neochat.Forgotpassword$1.onClick(Forgotpassword.java:54)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 08:34:09.474: E/AndroidRuntime(21657):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't call `getString` on an `UPDATE` command. 
That'll only work with a `SELECT` command

Comment: :Can you suggest the method to get the value from cursor to string variable ...here ?

Comment: `but I am getting the exact output` what do you mean ?

Comment: your logcat log says otherwise. your update is probably working, but you're not getting any column values back from the db. What are you trying to get when you call getString()?

Comment: I need my old password to be updated with new one ..see the thing is happening here is in my database value is updating but after this function the application is suddenly getting stopped ... showing the error

Answer (score 0):

before retrieving data from a cursor you need to call cursor.moveToFirst() or cursor.moveToNext().

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. An update query (best done using the dedicated update method, btw) returns the number of affected rows.

There will never be a "PASSWORD" column in the result of an update query.

Comment: dude I am getting the output...the value is updating in database ... but the application is again getting stopped. what to do ..why is this error showing my column PASSWORD do not exists? in DB the same column is updating..it do exist.